# Why is java -version returning the wrong version even though the path is set correctly?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to build a maven project but keep getting error:

> Fatal error compiling: invalid target release 16

If I look at my java version

```
java -version
```

I can see it is the wrong one:
openjdk version "11.0.11"
even though my path env var is set correctly to c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin

If I do

```
mvn -version
```

then it returns the correct one:
Java version: 1.8.0_291

I have opened a new command shell.  Same result.
I have rebooted the machine, same result.  I have deleted recursively the folders that contained those wrong versions.  Same result.

Now I do "where java" and it shows 3 locations remain.  2 are correct but the 3rd shows the culprit:
c:\program files\jetbrains\intellij idea community edition 2021.1.2\jbr\bin.
java -version in there shows "openjdk version "11.0.11 2021-04-20"

why is intellij java overriding my java?

Any ideas?

Comment: IntelliJ doesn't care what's on your path. Go into Project Structure, that's where you configure what JDK to use. There's a similar setting for Maven (Preferences > Build Execution Deployment > Build Tools > Maven). You can also configure which version of Java modules are targeted to in Project Structure (Java 13 JDK can compile code to run in Java 8, say, but you lose the ability to use Java 13 features obviously) but that should be picked up from your POM automatically, you don't have to configure it

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your system and your configuration.

1. Maven and other tools don't care about your PATH. They use the system java registry service to figure out which java they prefer. What does this service look like? Depends on your OS. On windows its registry keys. On mac it's `/usr/bin/java` which is a softlink that redirects to other stuff. Even if they don't, they'll look at JAVA_HOME (the environment variable) and use that. They don't use the PATH.
2. Just because some java dir is on your path doesn't mean anything if a `java` executable is in some earlier PATH. Note on e.g. mac and many linux distros, `/usr/bin/java` is a thing, and `/usr/bin` is usually at the start of your PATH variable. This is a java that redirects to the real java. On ubuntu you'd configure this with `java-alternatives`, etcetera.
3. If running in an IDE, the IDE doesn't care about any of this and has its own configuration.

The exact explanation of what to do depends on a combinatorial explosion of your JDK installation(s), your OS (and not just 'linux', the specific distro), and the tool you use, that listing it all is a fool's errand.

Comment: My Windows10 JAVA_HOME is set to c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291.  It's ignored.  I have set the same path in IntelliJ (File > Project Structure > Project, Modules, and SDKs).  It too is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the module and project JDK is set to 16 JDK:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.   I discovered the problem.  Even though I had version 1.8 set in the fields you've highlighted, java -version was still showing 11.0.11 2021-04-20, the default version.  It turns out that Intellij sets the default version in the pom file.  Even though I had the pom set to 1.8, further down the file Intellij had set it to the default, giving it priority